# Application Installaton Failed

Tags: android

I have updated my android studio from version 1.0 to 2.1 preview 5
Now when i run my application on real device it always gives this message

[image]

My phone contains enough free space , but it display this message every time.

Comment: Does it have plenty of free space or just enough?  You actually require more free space (much more) than the size of the apk to actually install it.

Comment: phone has 600 MB of free internal space and 3 GB of free external space.

Comment: External doesn't matter.  But yeah, that seems like it should be more than sufficient.

Comment: How big is the APK you're trying to install?

Answer (score 0):

I also have deploying issues with the virtual machines in Android Studio 2.0. 
I partial resolved them by doing this:

1. from menu Tools > Android uncheck "Enable ADB Integration"
2. repeat step 1 but this time to check "Enable ADB Integration"

I have to do this every time i open AS but at least i can deploy the app. 
Probably this is not the case for a real device but give it a try.